# Gnome Workspace grid disconfigured on screen lock

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I have the Gnome extension "Workspace Grid". I have it configured with a grid of 3x3, and it works without a problem. But when my computer goes automatically on screen lock, after 5 minutes on inactivity, and then I log back in, it has transformed in a grid of 1x9.

To get it back to its original configuration, I gotta deactivate and reactivate the gnome extensions.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: As per GNOME's security policy, whenever you enter the lock screen *all* the extensions get disabled automatically until you get back in, and then the extensions get re-enabled. Looks like somehow Workspace Grid is failing to reload after unlocking. Consider reporting a bug to the developer. Restarting GNOME shell (by pressing <Alt><F2>, then entering `r` and finally pressing <Enter>) would most probably solve the issue temporarily.

Comment: Submitted https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid/issues/112